# Length of longest substring with numbers only

Tags: python, text-processing

I would like to give as an input a string and to receive as an output the length of the longest substring with numbers only.

However, first of all, I would like to be a bit more flexible on the "substring with numbers only" definition.

Specifically, I would like to do what I want with substrings which consist let's say at least by 70% of numbers (so not necessarily 100%).

Therefore, if I have this sentence:

```
sentence = 'I am 14 a data 1,a211 899 scientist 1he3'
```

then the answer should be `10` coming from the substring `1,a211 899` since this substring has 7 out 10 characters (70%) as digits.

It is not (so) necessary to take into the whitespaces so you can remove them from the beginning if this makes things easier for you.

How can I efficiently do this?

Answer (score 2):

With [`re_pattern.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.finditer) function and specific regex pattern:

```
import re

sentence_1 = 'I am 99 a data 1,211 scientist'
pat = re.compile(r'\b\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?')   # prepared pattern
max_num_len = max(len(m.group()) for m in pat.finditer(sentence_1))
print(max_num_len)  # 5
```

---

Additional **extended** approach for updated condition *"longest substring which consist let's say at least by 70% of numbers (so not necessarily 100%)."*:

```
sentence = 'I am 14 a data 1,a211 899 scientist 1he3'
num_percent = 70

main_pat = re.compile(r'\b\S*\d+\S*(?:\s*\S*\d+\S*){1,}')
nondigits_pat = re.compile(r'\D+')  # pattern to match non-digit characters
max_substr_len = 0

for m in main_pat.finditer(sentence):
    val = m.group()  # matched substring value
    val_len = len(val)
    if (len(nondigits_pat.sub('', val)) / val_len * 100 >= num_percent) \
            and val_len > max_substr_len:
        max_substr_len = val_len

print(max_substr_len)   # 10
```

Comment: Thank you :) . Although in the end the second "problem" matters more since I expect to have some (undesirable) letters among my numbers so if you can come up with some good about the second then it would be great.

Comment: When i tested the above code without "," (eg: string = 'I am 99 a data 1211 scientist') in the number, it throws an error.

Comment: @PoeteMaudit. ok, for the 2nd condition - can there be entries that starts with letters like `a1,22.05d` ?

Comment: Yes, you should assume that they can and that in general a letter may appear anywhere really.

Comment: @j23, good catch, thanks. Fixed

Comment: Please check my edited post towards the bottom for a clarification. (P.S. upvote for your effort thus far).

Comment: @PoeteMaudit, please, see my comment below the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57459459/length-of-longest-substring-with-numbers-only/57459550?noredirect=1#comment101392809_57459459

Comment: Hey, I saw that but basically this does not change anything to what I want to do (than some words) so ...

Comment: @PoeteMaudit, you can't call "substring" - whitespace characters makes "substring" notion completely arbitrary in such context. And the one can not recognize whether `1aaa 33445 a3 55,9 dd1` is "your" substring or 5 separate strings

Comment: Cool, I will change the wording at my post but the goal is the same. (I just thought that any string within another string can be called substring; Otherwise I would now have to write string only with numbers in a string?)

Comment: Just for your information: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57459998/9024698.

Comment: @PoeteMaudit, see my update

Comment: Thank you (upvote for your effort). How is it better than adnanmuttale's below and specifically how faster it is? (Just asking so that you can explain me quickly - I am not saying that it is not better). (Seems like it is O(n) while adnanmuttale's is O(n2) ?)

Comment: By the way, I am not sure what this `r'\b\S*\d+\S*(?:\s*\S*\d+\S*){1,}'` is about?

Answer (score 1):

**1)** This solution does not works for white space, but is more efficient than the other solution(check below):

```
s = 'I am 14 a data 1,a211 scientist 1he3'

def check(w):
    digits = [d for d in w if d.isdigit()]
    return len(digits)/len(w) >= 0.6


l = s.split()

result = ''
for w in l:
    if check(w):
       if len(w) > len(result):
           result = w

print(result)
```

Output:

```
1,a211
```

**2)** If you want also to consider white spaces, you should check every substring for your condition, which is holding not less than 60% of digits:

```
s1 = 'I am 14 a data 1,a211 scientist 1he3'
s2 = 'I am 14 a data 1,a211 889 scientist 1he3' 

#this function is predicate that check if substring hold more then 60% of digits
def check(w):
    digits = [d for d in w if d.isdigit()]
    return len(digits)/len(w) >= 0.6

def get_max(s):
  result = ''
  for i in range(len(s)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(s)):
      #check if the substring is valid and have larger size 
      if check(s[i:j]):
        if (j-i) > len(result):
          result = s[i:j]
  return result

print(get_max(s1))
print(get_max(s2))
```

Output:

```
1,a211
1,a211 889
```

The last solution has time complexity of `O(n^2)`, while the first one is `O(n)`, where `n` is the size of the string.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Would this work for a substring which contains numbers separated by a whitespace? e.g. s = 'I am 14 a data 1,a211 889 scientist 1he3' then the output should be `10` for `1,a211 889`.

Comment: Please check my edited post towards the bottom if you want about this clarification.

Comment: @PoeteMaudit I edited my answer, if you find test cases where my solution fails please add a comment.

Comment: Hey thank you for your effort (upvote). Please feel free to add some comments to explain a bit what you do at your code.

Comment: By the way the truth is that I do not really need to consider the whitespaces. So we could remove the whitespaces from the whole string at the beginning and then run your first solution which looks faster. Although now that I am thinking it is preferable for me to have the whitespaces too.

Comment: If you removed all white spaces then you can not split the string using white space as delimiter.

Comment: By the way, I would suggest that you remove your first solution since it is quite misleading because I am interested in substrings with multiple words so your first solution does not work for that :) . Your second solution looks good though. I am just thinking if somehow could be done in O(n). ;)

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @adnanmuttaleb's code. Instead of checking all slices/substrings, just check the ones that start and end with digits. I believe the time complexity (or at least the number of iterations) is: O(n! / (2 * (n - 2)!)) Where 'n' is the number of digits in the original string. This calculation does not take the complexity of itertools.combinations into account.

```
def get_longest_substring(string):

    from itertools import combinations

    def is_valid_substring(substring):
        return len([char for char in substring if char.isdigit()]) / len(substring) >= 0.7

    digit_indecies = [index for index, char in enumerate(string) if char.isdigit()]

    substrings = []
    for begin, end in combinations(digit_indecies, 2):
        substring = string[begin: end+1]
        if is_valid_substring(substring):
            substrings.append(substring)
    return max(substrings, key=len)

def main():

    string = "I am 14 a data 1,a211 899 scientist 1he3"

    longest_substring = get_longest_substring(string)
    print(longest_substring)

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
1,a211 899
```

Comment: Cool but this "just check the ones that start and end with digits" is an assumption to start with. Not a bad one but not a necessary one either. Also, your code becomes a little bit too long.